# Yammer share and embedding the comments on a web application

Tags: javascript, yammer, social-media

I am facing an issue related to the yammer integration, want to share the articles to yammer.com from my web app and embed the comments of corresponding article to my web app.

I was ***able to publish & share*** the link to Yammer using JS SDK code as below,

```
yam.platform.yammerShareOpenPopup(options);
```

but it is not returning any **feedId** or **threadId** of the shared item.

```
   /* Like to have this kind of API to get the FeedId and ThreadId of the post */ 

    yam.platform.yammerShareOpenPopup(options).then((feedId,threadId)=>{

         // lot of codes
    });
```

How can I get the feed Id and thread Id after sharing the post, or Is there any REST API available to share and get the feedID/ThreadID?
I have searched many related Q&As and Yammer Docs, but bad luck I couldn't find any answers or APIs.

Please share your thoughts, any comments or links also be helpful.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you post a message with the [Yammer Share Button](https://developer.yammer.com/docs/share-button) you don't get this information by design. It's connecting into what was originally the bookmarklet page for Yammer (/message/new). Only yam.platform.yammerShare() is the documented (read: supported) API.

If you want to post a message and get information back you need to make a direct call to the REST API. Try out [posting messages](https://developer.yammer.com/docs/messages-json-post) from the Developer Center and you'll see something like the following:

[image]

You can see that you get back various pieces of metadata that you are looking for including Thread ID. The trade-off here is that the Share button is simple, but basic. With the REST API (using server-side code, or the [JS SDK](https://developer.yammer.com/docs/js-sdk)) you can have greater capabilities and control.